# Using <form> to update BooleanField in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Using Django 1.6 with Python 2.7.

My model has a BooleanField variable, and I want the user to be able to change this via POST by clicking a button to change it from False to True, or vice versa. Having issues rendering the template.

Model currently:

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Good = models.BooleanField()
    Image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name
```

App urls is:

```
url(r'^(?P<Pic_id>\d+)/$', views.single_picture, name='single_picture'),
```

In the template I have:

```
<form action="{% url 'single_picture' Pic.Good %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if Pic.Good %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.Good }}" value="False" />
    <label for="{{ Pic.Good }}">False</label><br />
    {% else %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.Good }}" value="True" />
    <label for="{{ Pic.Good }}">True</label><br />
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="good" />
</form>
```

And for my view I have:

```
def single_picture(request, Pic_id):

if request.method == 'GET':
    pic = get_object_or_404(Pic, pk=Pic_id)
    latest_pictures_list = Pic.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic, 'latest_pictures_list': latest_pictures_list})
elif request.method == 'POST':
    pic = get_object_or_404(Pic, pk=Pic_id)
    latest_pictures_list = Pic.objects.all()
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Pic.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic, 'error_message': 'uhhhh...',
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic}))
```

I'm not sure if there are multiple errors at this point or not. Currently when trying to view the template, I get

```
Reverse for 'single_picture' with arguments '(True,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

for the '< form >' line. I'm guessing it's to do with my View?

Comment: Is inditation accurate here??? According to your question, its not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your template, in the line

`<form action="{% url 'single_picture' Pic.Good %}" method="post">`

Your regex in urls.py is `r'^(?P<Pic_id>\d+)/$'`, I'm guessing that it's expecting the id of the `Pic`object you return in the `GET` request  and not a boolean, in which case the line should be

`<form action="{% url 'single_picture' Pic.id %}" method="post">`

Likewise, in the lines underneath, there is`id="{{ Pic.Good }}"` which will display as HTML as `id=True` or `id=False`, which I suppose you don't want. You need to replace that bit by `id="{{Pic.id}}"`

Comment: If I make that change, I just get an updated version of the same NoReverseMatch error:

    `Reverse for 'pic' with arguments '(4,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

('(4,)' in this case is the Pic id).